# EDMX designer is missing and can't reinstall EF tools in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework

I am missing the edmx designer in VS 2010 SP1 Ultimate in Windows 7 64 bit. I uninstalled VS 2010 using VS2010_Uninstall-RTM.ENU.exe and reinstalled VS 2010 and SP1. When runing VS 2010, I got some messages like "The 'Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.BootstrapPackage.BootstrapPackage.... package did not load correctly". I also noticed that Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.Package.dll is missing. Then I did a "ADONETEntityFrameworkTools_enu.msi USING_EXUIH=1 /log "Log.txt" which gave a message "A later version of microsoft Visual Studio 2010 ADO.NET Entity Framework Tools is already installed". I looked at he log file but I couldn't determine the problem. How did it know there's a later version?

The EF tools entry does not show up in the control panel -> programs.

I had the EF June 2011 CTP installed but was uninstalled some time ago.

I also did "msiexec /update [DVD drive letter]:\VS10sp1-KB983509.msp /package {14DD7530-CCD2-3798-B37D-3839ED6A441C}" and got message "This action is only valid for products that are currently installed". This is odd because one installer tells me there's a later version and another installer tells me it's not! (from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/06/30/announcing-the-microsoft-entity-framework-june-2011-ctp.aspx)

I also did "devenv.exe /installvstemplates" and ran these installers: DACFramework_enu.msi, DACProjectSystemSetup_enu.msi & TSqlLanguageService_enu.msi.

I am out of ideas. How do I get the edmx designer back?
If VS thinks EF tools are already installed, why aren't they working? I couldn't find the SP1 version of ADONETEntityFrameworkTools_enu.msi. I am guessing there are remnants from the CTP. How do I do a thorough cleanup? I used the control panel to remove everything related to VS. My last idea is to use SysInternal's Process Explorer and possibly spend hours digging into this.

Comment: Reformat and start over. Just kidding. But seriously, it sounds like you need to uninstall everything related to EF and Visual Studio and then re-install only what you need.

Comment: Have you tried the [EntityFramework NuGet package](http://nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework)?

Comment: @jrummell I uninstalled everything and reinstalled VS2010 and SP1. This should be my starting fresh clean slate for VS. EntityFramework NuGet is just a newer EntityFramework.dll. It's more than what I need to start from a basic setup.

Comment: Maybe it is a stupid idea but I would try installing the June CTP again and then try uninstalling it again...

Comment: I know this will not help you now but next time remember to not install any Betas or CTPs on your real system - use virtual machines you can throw away once new version is available.

Comment: @Ladislav I don't like VMs. It means I have to install everything I use in my development environment which is a lot. Plus everything is slower in a VM and thaty annoys me. Next time I'll do a drive image before installing a ctp.

Comment: @Pawel I reinstalled the CTP and it worked. You can put it in an answer if you want credit.

Comment: @Tony: You will need to install it only once and backup VM before you start to use it. Installing CTPs on real system and use it for production work is way to big troubles.

Comment: I am glad it worked. I put it in an answer as you proposed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing the June CTP again and then try uninstalling it again...